# How to change the values of the push buttons in QT designer

Tags: python, qt, qt-designer

I am using the standard dialog box with ok and cancel options.i Have also added one more button exit.

```
self.dlg.show()                    
result=self.dlg.exec_()
print 'The result is',result
```

it is giving the result of 1 for ok. but it is giving the result of 0 for both cancel and the exit buttons. I want to assign different functionalities to both the buttons. So how to chnage the result values for both the buttons?
like i want to print the result value of exit to be 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the QDialogButtonBox, I'm afraid you cannot do what you want from QT Designer (at least I couldn't with a bit of research :D). According to the [Qt docs](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#DialogCode-enum), dialogs return either 0 or 1, so you need to specify the value by using custom code:

> In order to modify your dialog's close behavior, you can reimplement the functions accept(), reject() or done().

An easy way of doing it is to add the following SIGNAL/SLOT connections (in the generated Python file) to customize the result value after a particular button is clicked, this way:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox.button(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok), QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), lambda: Dialog.done(2))
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox.button(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel), QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), lambda: Dialog.done(1))
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.buttonBox.button(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Discard), QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), lambda: Dialog.done(0))
```

By using the `done(int)` slot, you overwrite the result value. In the example, I added via Qt Designer three standard buttons: Ok, Cancel, and Discard, and set a result value of 2, 1, and 0, respectively.

You should now get 0, 1, and 2 values from your `exec_()` call. If something doesn't work, double check your object names. For instance, if your QDialog is called MyDialog, use MyDialog.done(0).

---

If you are not using a QDialogButtonBox but QPushButtons directly, the SIGNAL/SLOT connection would be:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.myPushButton, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), lambda: Dialog.done(3))
```

By clicking that button, you close the dialog and obtain a result value of 3.